# SQL Server NTFS allocation unit size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

On Windows 2008 R2 running SQL Server 2008 R2 how imporatant is the NTFS allocation unit size on DISK IO performance. It appears to me that server admin who built the few servers for a mission critical app left NTFS allocation unit size (cluster size) to default 4 KB instead of 64 KB. SQL server is already installed.

Does it worth to take pain -- to uninstall SQL -- format the drive with 64 KB cluster size and reinstall SQL server?

Comment: On a sidenote; To benefit from a 64k block size, you need trace your chunks all the way through your I/O subsystem, to make sure the 64KB chunks are not split up into smaller chunks somewhere along the way. But I guess you already knew that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't need to uninstall/install: your data and log files should be on separate disk arrays/SAN Luns from the binaries.

Saying that, 64k NFTS cluster is highly recommended all over the place.
SQL Server does IO in extents which is 8x8k pages = 64k, basically.

For actual numbers on performance differences, I can only find this http://tk.azurewebsites.net/2012/08/ (Azure, but still SQL Server)

Comment: +1 True though system databases might be a little more cumbersome to move after the fact. If downtime can be afforded now I'd rather set the right alloc size everywhere and redistribute system dbs appropriately.

Comment: `SQL Server does IO in extents which is 8x8k pages = 64k, basically.` - is this the reason why Microsoft recommends 64K allocation unit formatting?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft also has a nice TechNet article, [Disk Partition Alignment Best Practices for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814(v=sql.100).aspx), that discusses Disk partition alignment as it relates to SQL Server 2008. In most cases, 64KB is the best choice. Best recommendation would be to make sure your partitions are aligned, test your I/O performance and if Latency and other specs are not to the level of performance that this mission critical app needs, plan for down-time and fix it right!

Comment: The latest gallery templates for Azure VMs with SQL Server 2012/2014 have 64KB stripe size for the OLTP template and 256KB for the datawarehouse (DW) one: http://tinyurl.com/p32eghd

Answer (score 2):

since you only get to do it absolutely right once before it goes to production, I'd say so but it depends on your usage patterns.  If you're not already live with the system I would grab the config file which acts as a unattended install file if you reference it during your reinstall.  That should make the reinstall much easier and consistent.

http://mycodelog.com/2010/09/28/sqlsilent/

Comment: You don't need to reinstall anything.